# Does trial and error have to be in gerund form for parallelism in the sentence below?

Tags: gerunds, parallelism

Does trial and error have to be in gerund form for parallelism in the sentence below? If so what would be the gerund form of trial and error?

> Instead I self taught myself by playing with others who have been formally taught, watching youtube videos, and trial and error.

Comment: 'I taught myself', not 'I self taught myself'. Your sentence is otherwise OK, except I would write 'and **by** trial and error', and also **YouTube** is written thus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, there isn’t really a gerund form of the phrase “trial and error.” Unlike other “method” words (e.g. guess + guessing, try + trying), “trial and error” is an idiomatic phrase. It’s more like a noun.

The phrase is pretty much always used as

> *Use* **trial and error** to complete this question.
>
> I *used* **trial and error** to get to this answer.
>
> That answer can only be reached *through* careless **trial and error.**